# Doctrine - ManyToOne with table between

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I want to create model which will have table users with reference to table CustomFieldValue nad table CustomField with reference to CustomFieldValue too. CustomFieldValue will have only id, value and two columns, one from users and second from CustomField. I want to have functionality like a dynamic adding a new fields in registration form. Is this good idea? If yes, please help me with this model, because it doesn't work:
User:

```
 /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users",cascade={"persist"})
     * 
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $sex;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $region;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;


    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomFieldValue",inversedBy="id")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $customValues;
```

CustomFieldValue:

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
    *ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mapped-by="id")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */

    private $user;


    /**
    *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomField", mapped-by="id" )
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */

    private $field;
```

CustomField:

```
 /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="required", type="boolean")
     */
    private $required;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomFieldValue", inversedBy="id")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customfield_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $customValues;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is a little off:

User Entity Should Be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomFieldValue", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $customValues;
```

CustomFieldValue Should Be:

```
/**
 *ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="customValues")
 */
private $user;


/**
*@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomField", mappedBy="customValues" )
*/

private $field;
```

CustomField should be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomFieldValue", inversedBy="field")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customfield_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $customValues;
```

You dont need the join columns when you are calling the `mappedBy` this already tells doctrine to look for the join column declaration on that field. For the mappedBy and inversedBy fields these are the fields that link the 2 together NOT the actual join column name.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response :) but it generare this warning: The mappings Flomedia\UserBundle\Entity\CustomFieldValue#field and Flomedia\UserBundle\Entity\CustomField#customValues are inconsistent with each other. Can you tell me what is incorrect? Moreover, can you explain me what do mappedBy and inversedBy?

Comment: It was a plural issue, you need to make sure that the property name matches. I have updated my answer so that they match

Comment: Ok.. I don't have an idea how it works. In User table I have strage column named user_id, I don't want it so I change user_id to id in code and the same situation was in CustonField. I have generated 3 tables now - User - it's ok. CustomField - it's ok and the CustomFieldValue - it hasn't got any field referenced to User and CustomField :( It has only id and value fields. If I don't change user_id to user, my database will sill doesn't have referenced between User / CustomField and CustomFieldValue...

Comment: Not trying to be rude but it sounds like you may need to brush on on associations a bit. Have a look at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html They have good examples and explanations of the the different types.